# How to find and print duplicate characters on string?

Tags: c, string

I would like to know how to print duplicate characters on string?
Moreover, print duplicates should not each letter individually, but simply a sequence of letters. The most often met the letter should be placed in front of the sequence. 
I have given string. The output I get the same string

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question so that it is makes sense and is readable.  These sentences do not make any sense:  "Moreover, print duplicates should not each letter individually, but simply a sequence of letters. The most often met the letter should be placed in front of the sequence."

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: For example
word "barracuda" --> "aaarrbcud"

Comment: @Pavel whats that pattern you printed its neither sorted nor original order?

Comment: First, the letter which occurs most often , followed by the letter , which is rarer

Comment: To rearrange the characters of a string to the beginning of the line were more frequently occurring characters

Comment: check the ans after edit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use counting sort.see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)
For arranging chars based on frequency just use 2d array array[255][2].

Have an array of size depending on range of char you have. For eg if you have all range of chars have an `array[255]` and just keep on incrementing each time a value is read. If you just have alphabet have `array[26]`.

Then just sort your array[][] based on first index using [qsort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126462/sorting-a-2d-array-with-qsort)

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

 int intcmp(const void *a,const void *b ){
 int *A = (int*)a;
 int *B = (int*)b;
 if( A[0]>B[0])
    return -1;
 if( A[0]<B[0])
    return 1;
 if( A[0]==B[0])
   return 0;
}
int main()
{
    char st[100];
    int ar[26][2]={0},size=0,i;
    scanf("%s",&st);

    for(i=0;st[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
       ar[st[i]-97][1]=st[i];
       ar[st[i]-97][0]++;
    }
    qsort(ar,26,sizeof(int)*2,intcmp);
    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
       while(ar[i][0]--)
       printf("%c",ar[i][1]);
    }
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: urraaadbc  -- > It must be aaarrbcud